# как поменять тему windows 10 через python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

**Пример темы windows которую нужно сменить через python**
[image: Пример темы windows]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю то ли это, но...

```
import os, time
os.system("""C:\WINDOWS\system32\rundll32.exe C:\WINDOWS\system32\themecpl.dll,OpenThemeAction C:\Users\xxx\Misc_computer_stuff\themes\my_fav_gr.theme""")
time.sleep(1)
os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM systemsettings.exe & close window")
```

[related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546818/how-do-i-change-the-current-windows-theme-programmatically)